# .pbtx (labelmap) file parsing

Tags: java, android, parsing, tensorflow

I am new in machine learning field, Just getting started.I have been building electronics component detector using TensorFlow Mobile for my minor project.
The problem is how to parse the .pbtx labelmap in android,this file format looks like JSON but it is not.

Here is a portion of my labelmap.pbtx file

```
item {
  id: 1
  name: 'Resistor'
}
item {
  id: 2
  name: 'Zener Diode'
}
item {
  id: 3
  name: 'LED'
}
```

After detection the thesorflow graph gives the id of detected components and I want to get the name using that class id of the component.

Like, if the `id=3` then I should `LED`.

Is there any parsor for pbtx file format in Java?
(Yes I know I can make a JSON array file for the labelmap and parse it but I don't want to do that.)